# Archeologists exploring dead planet find room where they commited suicide by asphyxiation

Tags: story-identification, space-exploration

I am trying to find the title of a science fiction book/story that I read many years ago (about 40!).

All that I can remember is that it involved explorers (I think they may have been archaeologists) on a dead planet that at one time had a civilisation. They find various artifacts including symbols that could be a written language. The event that sticks in my mind is the discovery of a room that has a fire in it that has been used by the last remaining members of the civilization to commit suicide by asphyxiation. I can't remember why! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 21):

Omnilingual, by H. Beam Piper. [On Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19445)

The part where the last Martians are discovered:

> "Yes; charcoal. I noticed a quantity of it around a couple of
>   hand-forges in the shop on the first floor. That's why you had so much
>   trouble breaking in; they'd sealed the room on the inside." He
>   straightened and went around the room, until he found a ventilator, and
>   peered into it. "Stuffed with rags. They must have been all that were
>   left, here. Their power was gone, and they were old and tired, and all
>   around them their world was dying. So they just came in here and lit the
>   charcoal, and sat drinking together till they all fell asleep. Well, we
>   know what became of them, now, anyhow."

And another matching point is of course the analysis of the Martians' written language, which is the main plot thread.

Comment: Nice one. Did you read this?

Comment: Bingo! Well done! I have just found the story in the book that I originally read it in and that I still have in my collection. Very grateful.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is The Pirate by Poul Anderson.

In it there is a world hit by the radiation from a super-nova and the some of the inhabitants kill themselves to not suffer from radiation sickness. They use asphyxiation during  a final party as the method of choice.